# Regular expression for Corporate Identification Number (CIN)

Tags: angular, regex, cin

I'm trying to validate CIN number which has specific pattern according to Indian Government Regulations, Pattern is as follows :-

- CIN is a 21 digits alpha-numeric code.
- It starts with either alphabet letter U or L.
- Next five characters are reserved for digits (0-9).
- Next two places are occupied by alphabet letters(A-Z-a-z).
- Next four places are taken by digits(0-9).
- Next three characters are reserved for alphabet letters (A-Za-z).
- Next six characters are digits(0-9).
- It should not contain any special character or whitespaces

[CIN DECODED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQxrT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Later, I've tried this pattern below for CIN number and It worked perfectly fine

```
cinNumber = '^([LUu]{1})([0-9]{5})([A-Za-z]{2})([0-9]{4})([A-Za-z]{3})([0-9]{6})$';
```